# Blocking the main thread on Android while doing task asynchronously

Tags: android, asynchronous, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I've been struggling to understand the difference between multi threading v asynchronous programming on Android. Mainly, why a long running task needs to be taken off the main thread, even if that task is done asynchronously with something like a coroutine.

It makes sense to me given the explanation that even though a long running task may be asynchronous, that it's still work being done on the UI thread. So even though the asynchronous code isn't blocking, it's the work that matters and not so much that it's blocking. That seems to make sense.

However, maybe just nuances in the language that I'm not aware of, but a single threaded language like JavaScript that can't delegate it's work over to any other separate thread works asynchronously as well, but you can have long running tasks in JavaScript a asynchronous functions and never get any errors signifying that you're doing too much work on the main thread and see UI performance hits from it.

Why is it that you still have to take code off the main thread on Android even if a task is suspended, and not in a language like javascript that only relies on one thread?

Comment: I believe asynchronous functions are performed in other threads under the hood, but you the programmer don't have to manage or deal with the underlying thread-based concurrency, you just need to program to the (presumably simpler) asynchronous API

Comment: Try making a _synchronous_ REST call from one of your activities, and you'll see what happens.  The entire app will block during the REST call, during which time your end user would probably have a really bad experience, as most of the app would appear to be frozen and unresponsive during this time.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen right, the question isn't so much about synchronous versus asynchronous, it's about multi threaded (so taking the app off the main thread) versus running an asynchronous operation (now adays using something like a coroutine) on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it that you still have to take code off the main thread on Android even if a task is suspended

You don't. The only rule is

> Any single event taken from the main thread's event queue shouldn't take long to handle.

where "long" is probably everything above a millisecond or two.

If you perform a blocking, sync operation in an event handler, it counts towards the duration of that event handler's execution.

If you perform a non-blocking, async operation in an event handler, the handler actually completes as soon as it initiates the operation, making sure there will be another event placed on the queue later on, when the result of the operation is ready.

That's the essence of cooperative vs. preemptive multithreading: in the former case, the user code is responsible to chop the total task into several lightweight events, while in the latter case, the OS enforces it regardless of what the code is doing. Since the entire GUI must be run on a single thread, preemptive multithreading is not an option.

So, specifically, in Kotlin you can write

```
launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    val user = makeRestCall("/users/$id")
    usernameText.text = user.name
}
```

with some `suspend fun makeRestCall(url: String)`.

Comment: A couple things, the code posted would crash with an ANR error wouldn't it? Because you're running the long running operation in `Dispatchers.Main`. If it's the case that it  wouldn't crash with an ANR, why would you ever run anything on any other thread? such as `Dispatchers.IO`?

Comment: With the basic sanity assumption that `makeRestCall` is a suspending function implemented in terms of an async API, there is no ANR. If you happen to use a blocking API (highly unusual on Android and not recommended), then you would have to resort to `val user = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { makeRestCall("/users/$id") }`. In this case `makeRestCall` would be a plain, non-suspendable function. You would still `launch` the coroutine on the `Main` dispatcher, though.